# Problem with empty value of variable in SWIFT

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm making simple app- single view app with segues. I've create a model with few variables:

```
import Foundation

class ActualValues {
var id: String = "ID:"
var product: String?
var issue: String?
```

In deferent view controller I can change and save value of this (for example id):

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {



var workModel: ActualValues?
var closureBlock: (() -> Void)?

@IBOutlet weak var idTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var idCheckButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}


@IBAction func idCheckButtonDidPress(_ sender: UIButton) {
    workModel?.id = "ID: \(idTextField.text!)"
    closureBlock?()
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func configureID(model: ActualValues) {
    workModel = model
   }
}
```

And now, I want to take my variable "id" value and send it to the server. If I do that, the value of id is empty. And this is my problem. I created func in other model:

```
func startSending() {
    db.collection("\(currentMonth())").document("Damian").collection("Michal").addDocument(data: [
        "ID": "\(String(describing: av.id))",
        "Start": "\(currentDate())",
        "Product": "\(String(describing: av.product))"
    ]) { err in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error writing document: \(err)")
        } else {
            print("Document successfully written!")
        }
    }
```

Anyone can help me? Problem is because I can't send id value to the server- id is empty.

PS: I've used closure becouse I had a problem with display actual id in label on my HomeViewController.

Comment: I couldn't see where you called `configureID(model:)` function.

Comment: I'm using it in my MainViewController for prepare(for segue) func.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an instance of `ActualValues` for `workModel` first. Now your `workModel` is `nil` and you can't add an `id` to your property (`workModel`). You can set a breakpoint to `idCheckButtonDidPress` and print `workModel` to see if it is `nil`.

Your `ActualValues` class must be like ->

```swift
class ActualValues {
    var id: String
    var product: String?
    var issue: String?

  init(id: String, product: String?, issue: String?) {
    self.id = id
    self.product = product
    self.issue = issue
  }
}
```

---

And then you should call `configureID` with new model ->

```swift
@IBAction func idCheckButtonDidPress(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let model = ActualValues(id: "ID: \(idTextField.text!)", product: nil, issue: nil)
    configureID(model: model)
    closureBlock?()
    dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

---

Now you have an instance of `ActualValues` and we added `id` into it. You can use `workModel` to send the object.

Comment: I think it's more complicated. I've tried do that but I have a lot of errors. I have file with class ActualValues, and I want to store values from few ViewControllers there. For example I want to store "var id" from IdViewController, and store "var product" from productViewController. So I can't use this init in few controllers. Maybe You know better way to store that variables?
And really, really thank You for your answer :)

Comment: I hoped my answer was the correct one but I realise your issue not about just a storage of the property, I think you should ask another question for your structure or issues. You can find the solution more faster in that way.